# 2 unknown one equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sorry for the bad title selection I dont know how to make it more specific/self explanatory enough. Well here goes:

I have this equation:

$$
y(t) = \frac{1 - ka \cdot d(t)}{1-a \cdot d(t)}.
$$

I want to find $d(t)$. $y(t)$ is my observation signal. I know $k$. I don't know $a$. Is there a way to express $d(t)$ in terms of $y(t)$? $a$ is a constant. $d(t)$ is a time dependent variable. Any adaptive filter to solve this equation?

Keith

Comment: Multiply by the denominator; collect the terms with $d$; divide by the coefficient of $d$.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate Gerry's comment:

$$
y(t) = \frac{1 - ka \cdot d(t)}{1-a \cdot d(t)} \implies y(t) - a \cdot y(t) \cdot d(t) = 1 - ka \cdot d(t).
$$

Thus we obtain that $a [k - y(t)] \cdot d(t) = 1 - y(t)$, so that

$$
d(t) = \frac{1}{a} \cdot \frac{1 - y(t)}{k - y(t)} .
$$